# Expectation on Mock Object doesn't seem to be met (Moq)

Tags: unit-testing, moq, expect

I'm experiencing some odd behavior in Moq - despite the fact that I setup a mock object to act a certain way, and then call the method in the exact same way in the object I'm testing, it reacts as if the method was never called.

I have the following controller action that I'm trying to test:

```
public ActionResult Search(string query, bool includeAll)
{
    if (query != null)
    {
        var keywords = query.Split(' ');
        return View(repo.SearchForContacts(keywords, includeAll));
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

My unit test code:

```
public void SearchTestMethod() // Arrange
    var teststring = "Anders Beata";
    var keywords = teststring.Split(' ');
    var includeAll = false;
    var expectedModel = dummyContacts.Where(c => c.Id == 1 || c.Id == 2);
    repository
        .Expect(r => r.SearchForContacts(keywords, includeAll))
        .Returns(expectedModel)
        .Verifiable();

    // Act
    var result = controller.Search(teststring, includeAll) as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    repository.Verify();
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    AssertThat.CollectionsAreEqual<Contact>(
        expectedModel, 
        result.ViewData.Model as IEnumerable<Contact>
    );
}
```

where `AssertThat` is just a class of my own with a bunch of assertion helpers (since the `Assert` class can't be extended with extension methods... sigh...).

When I run the test, it fails on the `repository.Verify()` line, with a `MoqVerificationException`:

```
Test method MemberDatabase.Tests.Controllers.ContactsControllerTest.SearchTestMethod()
threw exception:  Moq.MockVerificationException: The following expectations were not met:
IRepository r => r.SearchForContacts(value(System.String[]), False)
```

If I remove `repository.Verify()`, the collection assert fails telling me that the model returned is `null`. I have debugged and checked that `query != null`, and that I am taken into the part of the `if` block where the code is run. No problems there.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect it's because the array you're passing into your mocked repository (the result of `teststring.Split(' ')`) is not the same object as the one that actually gets passed in from the Search method (the result of `query.Split(' ')`).

Try replacing the first line of your setup code with:

```
repository.Expect(r => r.SearchForContacts(
    It.Is<String[]>(s => s.SequenceEqual(keywords)), includeAll))
```

... which will compare each element of the array passed to your mock with the corresponding element in the `keywords` array.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick immeditely! =) It seems I have to read up on Moq, and specifically on when and how to use the It... constructs.