# Moq Match and Verify Array / IEnumerable parameters in method setup

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm having problems verifying Ienumerable / Array type parameters when setting up expectation for methods call on my mock objects.  I think since it's matching different references it doesn't consider it a match.  I just want it to match the contents of the array, sometimes I don't even care about the order.

```
mockDataWriter.Setup(m => m.UpdateFiles(new string[]{"file2.txt","file1.txt"} ) );
```

Ideally I want something that works like the following, I could probably write an extension method to do this.

```
It.Contains(new string[]{"file2.txt","file1.txt"})

It.ContainsInOrder(new string[]{"file2.txt","file1.txt"})
```

The only built in way I can match these right now is with the predicate feature, but it seems this problem is common enough it should be built in.

Is there a built in way to match these types, or extension library I can use.  If not I'll just write an extension method or something.

Thanks

Comment: See if this question/answer helps at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220013/expectation-on-mock-object-doesnt-seem-to-be-met-moq

Answer (score 8):

Had to implement some custom matchers, haven't found any other built in way to accomplish this in version 3.  Used http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart as a resource.

```
public T[] MatchCollection<T>(T[] expectation)
{
  return Match.Create<T[]>(inputCollection => (expectation.All((i) => inputCollection.Contains(i))));
}

public IEnumerable<T> MatchCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> expectation)
{
  return Match.Create<IEnumerable<T>>(inputCollection => (expectation.All((i) => inputCollection.Contains(i))));
}


public void MyTest()
{

...

mockDataWriter.Setup(m => m.UpdateFiles(MatchCollection(new string[]{"file2.txt","file1.txt"}) ) );

...


}
```

Comment: Note that this just checks if all expected values are in the inputCollection, not the other way around. The inputCollection can still contain items that are not in the expectation.

Answer (score 6):

Previous answer by Oleg does not handle case where `inputCollection` has elements that are not in `expectation`.

For example:

```
MatchCollection(new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 })
```

will match inputCollection `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` when it clearly shouldn't.

Here's the complete matcher:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CollectionMatcher<T>(IEnumerable<T> expectation)
{
    return Match.Create((IEnumerable<T> inputCollection) =>
                        !expectation.Except(inputCollection).Any() &&
                        !inputCollection.Except(expectation).Any());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need two separate methods for array and IEnumerable:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> MatchCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> expectation)
{
    return Match.Create<IEnumerable<T>>(inputCollection => expectation.All(inputCollection.Contains));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My refined version:

```
// ReSharper disable once CheckNamespace
namespace Moq
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public static class MatchCollection<T>
    {
        public static TEnum SequenceEquals<TEnum>(TEnum expectation)
            where TEnum : IEnumerable<T>
        {
            return Match.Create<TEnum>(inputCollection => expectation.SequenceEqual(inputCollection));
        }

        public static TEnum SetEquals<TEnum>(TEnum expectation)
            where TEnum : IEnumerable<T>
        {
            var set = new HashSet<T>(expectation);
            return Match.Create<TEnum>(inputCollection => set.SetEquals(inputCollection));
        }

        public static TEnum Contains<TEnum>(TEnum expectation)
            where TEnum : IEnumerable<T>
        {
            var set = new HashSet<T>(expectation);
            return Match.Create<TEnum>(inputCollection => set.IsSubsetOf(inputCollection));
        }

        public static TEnum IsContainedIn<TEnum>(TEnum expectation)
            where TEnum : IEnumerable<T>
        {
            var set = new HashSet<T>(expectation);
            return Match.Create<TEnum>(inputCollection => set.IsSubsetOf(inputCollection));
        }
    }
```